# trigger works but error when creating in Mysql 5.x

Tags: mysql, triggers

phpmyadmin 4.4.15.7
mysql 5.6.37

my TRIGGER is created but I get an error

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER trg_newslistusers AFTER INSERT ON lisc_user_usergroup_map
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO lisc_acymailing_listsub
SELECT b.group_id, a.subid,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), NULL, 1  FROM lisc_acymailing_subscriber a INNER JOIN  lisc_user_usergroup_map b ON a.userid = b.user_id;
END |
```

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '|' at line 6*

Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you creating the trigger from MySQL command line?.

Comment: no in phpmyadmin 4.4.15.7
on mysql 5.6.37

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a single sql statement in the trigger body, there is no need for begin-end, nor for changing the statement delimiter:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_newslistusers AFTER INSERT ON lisc_user_usergroup_map
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT IGNORE INTO lisc_acymailing_listsub
SELECT b.group_id, a.subid,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), NULL, 1  FROM lisc_acymailing_subscriber a INNER JOIN  lisc_user_usergroup_map b ON a.userid = b.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it in that way

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER trgNewslist AFTER INSERT ON lisc_usergroups
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO lisc_acymailing_list
SELECT `title`, '', 0, `id`,1, 60, LOWER(REPLACE(`title`, ' ', '' )), '#000000', 1,0,0, 'list', 'all','none', 'all', 0, ''
FROM lisc_usergroups
ORDER BY  `id` DESC
LIMIT 1;
UPDATE lisc_acymailing_list SET `alias`= REPLACE(`alias`, 'ß', 'ss');
UPDATE lisc_acymailing_list SET `alias`= REPLACE(`alias`, 'ä', 'ae');
UPDATE lisc_acymailing_list SET `alias`= REPLACE(`alias`, 'ë', 'e');
UPDATE lisc_acymailing_list SET `alias`= REPLACE(`alias`, 'ï', 'ie');
UPDATE lisc_acymailing_list SET `alias`= REPLACE(`alias`, 'ö', 'oe');
UPDATE lisc_acymailing_list SET `alias`= REPLACE(`alias`, 'ü', 'ue');
UPDATE lisc_acymailing_list SET `alias`= REPLACE(`alias`, '"', '');
END;
```

without | at the end
if I dont put DELIMITER | on top it does not work

i find the syntax really strange

thanks to alll